# Как сделать проверку формы в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, проверка

Мне нужно чтобы человек вводил что-то в формате 'text_text', в противном случае будет выдавать ошибку.

Формат: `OnlyLetters_OnlyLetters`

Как я могу это сделать в минимальное количество строк?

Comment: формализуйте формат. Добавьте больше примеров подходящих и неподходящих строк

Comment: Проверяйте ввод регулярным выражением

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем "в минимальное количество строк" (даже совсем не "в минимальное количество строк" ;) ), тем не менее рабочий вариант, который можно оптимизировать и рефакторить:

```
def checker(text):
    parts = text.split('_')

    if len(parts) != 2:
        return False

    for p in parts:
        if not p.isalpha():
            return False

    return True
```

Возвращает:

```
>>> checker('Only_Letters_Only_Letters')
False
>>> checker('Only42_Letters')
False
>>> checker('OnlyLetters')
False
>>> checker('OnlyLetters_OnlyLetters')
True
```